# Android Bluetooth ConnectThread example error?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Why does the Eclipse development environment complain that the private modifier is invalid in the android [Bluetooth Connecting as client ConnectThread example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html)? Can a private class have public members? The error messge is:

> Illegal modifier for class
>   ConnectThread; only public, abstract,
>   and final are permitted.

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }
    public void run() {
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }
        manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this in a file by itself? This will only work if it is a class which is a member of another class.